# at / atd command on debian

Tags: unix, debian, package

I want to use the at or atd unix command to schedule jobs but so far i've not been able to find the right package or path to use it.

Here is my debian info:

```
11:04:23 (xxx@xxx in ~) cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.16.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Debian 4.8.4-1) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... my bad, i actually didn't apt-get update before trying to install at.